# How to activate open Excel workbook from Outlook?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

If the user running this Outlook macro has the spreadsheet open it will open as a read only.

I don't want the user to have to close it to run the macro. I am trying to activate the open spreadsheet.

How could I focus on a spreadsheet that may already be open?

```vb
Sub GetSelectedItems()
    Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Dim excelapp As Excel.Application
    Dim xWb As Excel.Workbook
    
    'Sets email items
    Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
    Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection
    
    'opens excel application and workbook
    Set excelapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    'Set xWb =
    
    excelapp.Workbooks("test.xlsm").Activate
    
    if err.number = 9 then
        Set xWb = excelapp.Workbooks.Open("K:\test.xlsm")
    end if
    
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try to 'GET' an open Excel session. If the resultant object = Nothing then you can CREATE one. In addition, you have to trap the possible errors, with "On Error Resume Next" and adequate code to run according it happens or not.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetSelectedItems()
    Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim excelapp As Excel.Application
    Dim xWb As Excel.Workbook


    'Sets email items
    Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
    Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection

    'loads current excel application session and workbook(s)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set excelapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If excelapp Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "there is no open Excel session"
        Set excelapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xWb = excelapp.Workbooks("test.xlsm")

    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set xWb = excelapp.Workbooks.Open("K:\test.xlsm")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
        
End Sub
```

Comment: i am still getting the same issue using getobject the workbook gives error 9 "Subscript out of range"

Comment: Specifically which line gives the error?

Comment: Error 9 after executing this line? (Set xWb = excelapp.Workbooks("test.xlsm"))

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the workbook you can use GetObject:

```vb
Sub TestGetObject()
    
    Dim wbName As String
    Dim objApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wB As Excel.Workbook
    
    wbName = "c:\Temp\blah.xlsx"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWb = GetObject(wbName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If objWb Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Not open"
        'workbook was not open: open it
        Set objWb = Workbooks.Open(wbName)
    Else
        Debug.Print "Already open"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Should work even if the workbook is already open in a different instance of Excel.